# Disable automatic upgrade when publishing a new minor version on google play console

Tags: android

I would like to implement A/B testing for my android app. To do this, I need to upload new versions to google play console many times per day. So I want to test my new features only on the new users, not on the current users.

Can I disable the android auto upgrade for current users?

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible on google-play

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10312443)

Comment: @LoganWayne - the question was Can I - the answer is No - do not really understand your problem ..

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Added better description. So I want to test my new features only on the new users, not on the current users.